# SQL, SELECT WHERE NOT EQUAL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:-

student table

```
std_ID|std_Name
------+--------
1     |  Jhon
2     |  Peter
3     |  Mic
4     |  James
```

studentBatch Table

```
B_std_ID|B_Batch_ID
--------+-------------
1       |  3
2       |  6
3       |  7
```

i want students those who are not enrolled in a batch,
i want this

```
std_ID|std_Name
------+--------
4     |  James
```

i tried this code

```
SELECT std_ID, std_Name FROM student , studentBatch WHERE std_ID <> B_std_ID;
```

but it didn't work, please help me with this

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON y.something = x.something WHERE y.something IS NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
SELECT std_ID, std_Name FROM student  WHERE std_ID not in (select B_std_ID from studentBatch )
```

Comment: thank you it works, but can you explain me why mine isn't working?

Comment: Your SQL doesn't work, because the SQL-engine does`n't know how to join the tables. That means, that SQL doesn't know that the content of std_ID is the same as b_std_id. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
select std_id
from student
where std_id not in (select B_std_ID from studentbatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * 
from student a 
where not exists (select * from studentbatch b where a.std_id = b.b_std_id)
```